# Can't display array element

Tags: php, arrays

I can't display an array element. If I use `print_r($array);` it shows me something like this:

> stdClass Object ([tableName1] => myValue1 [tableName2] => MyValue2 [tableName3] => myValue3 [tableName4] => myValue4)

But if I try to print the first element with `echo $array[0]` my site doesn't load (I get no error in IDE).

Here is the code of my function:

```
public function queryInfo($query) {
    $database = $this->connect();
    $result = $database->queryInfo($query);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }
    return $results; // this is the array i mean!
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Edit:
Solution: `echo $array[0]->myTableName;`

Comment: You need to use "==" instead of "=" in while.

Comment: No @D.Erashkin `=` is correct here as he's setting `$row` the next object of `$result` after every loop

Comment: @D.Erashkin no. `$row` is getting value from that `$result` , so it should be assignment operator

Comment: Try `echo $array[0][0]` or `$row = $result->fetch_array()` and then `echo $array[0]`

Comment: Ohhh..right. I hurried with the answer. Thanks IsThisJavascript Jigar Shah

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now it works. I added the solution into my Topic!

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to echo an object.
try to print_r($array[0]), if it's an object, you can access it's properties by using: $arrray[0]->propertyName

Answer (score 0):

```
public function queryInfo($query) {
    $database = $this->connect();
    $result = $database->queryInfo($query);
    $results = []
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
       $results.push($row);
    }
    return $results; // this is the array i mean!
}
```

Comment: Add explanation in answer. Follow SO guide lines for answers.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

You are fetching the result as an object.

```
$row = $result->fetch_object()
```

You can access object as $array[0]->tableName1 to get the value of column name tableName1 of first array.

Instead of fetch_object use fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) or fetch_array()

Comment: Yes this Works! thanks for your Help! Have a nice day!